# How to make sequentially Rest webservices calls with AngularJS?

Tags: web-services, angularjs, promise, sequential

I would like to know how we can make sequential webservices call with AngularJS?
To simplify, when we got the result of the first webservices we call the second one.
I already found a solution but I don't really like it. I think there must be a better solution, that's why I post my question.
This is my code (and it works).

```
var uploadFile = function(file) {
    szUrl = globalServ.datas.szUrl+"transactions/"+globalServ.transactionId+"/file";
    var postData = {};
    postData['name'] = "MyFile"+file;
    postData['file'] = $scope.wsFiles[file];
    $http({
        method: 'POST', 
        url:szUrl, 
        headers: {'Content-Type': false, 'Authorization': globalServ.make_base_auth()}, 
        transformRequest: formDataObject,
        data:postData,
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.qFiles[file].resolve(file);//This will allow to call "then" method
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.errorMsg = globalServ.getErrorMsg(status, data);
        $scope.filesAdded = false;
    });
}
$scope.uploadFiles = function() {
    delete $scope.errorStatus;

    $scope.qFiles = [];
    $scope.uploadOver = false;

    for(file in $scope.wsFiles) {
        var q1 = $q.defer();
        q1.promise.then(function(curFile) {
            if(curFile < $scope.wsFiles.length - 1) {
                uploadFile(curFile+1);
            } else {
                $scope.uploadOver = true;//We uploaded all contracts so now can stop to show loading button
            }
        });
        $scope.qFiles.push(q1);
    }
    uploadFile(0);//We start to upload contracts
};
```

All critical are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by accepting that if you're going to use promises, you want to use them everywhere.  They already provide many of the constructs that you're trying to create by hand.  In addition, try and avoid adding things to `$scope` (or any other global) unless absolutely necessary.  Build all your utility functions so that they're independent of the scope and of any view updating etc.

### Upload File

The next thing to do is to make `uploadFile` return a promise.  We also want it to not use $scope but rather take all the information it needs as an argument.  I therefore propose something like:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    szUrl = globalServ.datas.szUrl+"transactions/"+globalServ.transactionId+"/file";
    var postData = {};
    postData['name'] = "MyFile"+file.name;
    postData['file'] = file.data;
    return $http({  // <--------------------------- return the promise here
        method: 'POST', 
        url:szUrl, 
        headers: {'Content-Type': false, 'Authorization': globalServ.make_base_auth()}, 
        transformRequest: formDataObject,
        data:postData,
    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {  //<--- `.then` transforms the promise here
        return file
    }, function onError(response) {
        throw globalServ.getErrorMsg(response.status, response.data);
    });
}
```

where file is an object of the form `{name: 'file name', data: 'contents of file post'}`

### Upload Files

For upload files, we have to decide whether we want them to be uploaded in parallel or sequentially.  Parallel will usually be faster, but will use more resources (memory, bandwidth etc.).  You may want to do them in series if you need to do lots of other things at the same time.  You may also want to pick a third option (not covered here) of uploading say a maximum of 5 at a time in parallel.

Either way, we're going to create a function that takes an array of `file` objects and uploads them, then returns a promise that is resolved when the operation completes, or rejected if it fails.

#### Parallel

To do it in parallel, we just upload each file and then use `$q.all` to wait for all the uploads to finish.

```
function uploadFilesParallel(files) {
    var uploads = []
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        uploads.push(uploadFile(files[i]))
    }
    return $q.all(uploads)
}
```

#### Sequential

Uploading sequentially is just a little more complicated.  In principle what we need to do is have each operation wait for the previous operation to complete before starting.  To do this we first create a dummy initial operation that is represented by an already resolved promise.  We then keep track of the previous operation through the loop so that we can always wait for the previous operation before uploading.

```
function uploadFilesSequential(files) {
    var previous = $q.when(null) //initial start promise that's already resolved
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            previous = previous.then(function () { //wait for previous operation
                return uploadFile(files[i])
            })
        }(i)) //create a fresh scope for i as the `then` handler is asynchronous
    }
    return previous
}
```

### Usage

Finally your original uploadFiles operation that was attached to the scope.  At this point you can do all the necessary stuff to update your view.  Note how I haven't touched any globals up until this point.  The reason for this is to ensure that multiple calls to `uploadFilesSequential` or `uploadFilesParallel` won't conflict and cause problems.

I have not made the same guarantees about the following function.  If you call it multiple times in parallel, the multiple operations may cause strange behavior.

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function (parallel) {
    delete $scope.errorStatus;
    $scope.uploadOver = false;

    var files = [];

    for(file in $scope.wsFiles) {
        files.push({
            name: file,
            data: $scope.wsFiles[file]
        })
    }

    var uploadOperation
    if (parallel) {
        uploadOperation = uploadFilesParallel(files)
    } else {
        uploadOperation = uploadFilesSequential(files)
    }
    uploadOperation
        .then(function(file) {
            $scope.uploadOver = true;
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.errorMsg = err;
            $scope.filesAdded = false;
        });
};
```

Clearly if you're always using parallel or always using sequential uploading then you can simplify that slightly.  Note how simple it is to do this, all we have to do is handle the view logic and the actual implementation of `uploadFilesSequential` or `uploadFilesParallel` is completely hidden form us.  It's this encapsulation that is essential to making programming large systems possible.

### The Future

A future version of JavaScript is coming (EcmaScript 6) that will make the sequential version much easier.  You'll be able to re-write it approximately like:

```
var uploadFilesSequential = Q.async(function* (files) {
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        yield uploadFile(files[i])
    }
})
```

Where `yield` is a special keyword that waits for a promise to be resolved.  Unfortunately it'll probably be another couple of years before that's something you can use in real world code to be run in the browser.

Comment: I tested your sequential function and all webservices are called in the same time... (I saw it with the developer tools and the fact that only the first file is uploaded). But nice try, I liked your idea.

Comment: (I give you +1 for your idea). Just some little mistakes :
 uploadOperation = uploadFilesSequential(file **s**)
and 
} **)** (i) //create a fresh scope for i as t

Comment: @M07 I'd missed a `return` statement:

Comment: `previous = previous.then(function () { //wait for previous operation
  return uploadFile(files[i]) //wait for current operation
})`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript calls are always asynchronous. But as far as I know the only way to make javascript calls sync is by calling the new request in the succes/error handler of your first request.

Comment: That would make the calls "sequential" rather than "synchronous".  It is actually possible to make asynchronous HTTP requests in JavaScript, it's just not advised because if you do, you're website will hang/become unresponsive until the request completes.  If the request is big that could be multiple seconds.

Comment: The goal here is actually making the requests sequential rather than synchronous though, so you are correct.  The issue is how to handle lots of calls in parallel.  That's what creates the more complicated flow control problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to build a `.then()` chain as follows :

```
var uploadFile = function(index) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: globalServ.datas.szUrl + "transactions/" + globalServ.transactionId + "/file",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': false,
            'Authorization': globalServ.make_base_auth()
        },
        transformRequest: formDataObject,
        data: {
            name: "MyFile" + index,
            file: $scope.wsFiles[index]
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.errorMsg = globalServ.getErrorMsg(status, data);
        $scope.filesAdded = false;
    });
}
$scope.uploadFiles = function() {
    delete $scope.errorStatus;
    $scope.uploadOver = false;

    var p = $q.defer().resolve().promise;//Ready-resolved starter promise.

    function makeClosure(i) {
        return function() {
            return uploadFile(i);
        }
    }

    //Build a .then() chain
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.wsFiles.length; i++) {
        p = p.then(makeClosure(i));
    }

    //Add a terminal .then() to the chain.
    p.then(function() {
        $scope.uploadOver = true;//We uploaded all contracts so now can stop to show loading button
    });
};
```

I had to make a couple of assumptions so this may not be 100% correct, but should give you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: You have a problem because the `i` in the `.then` handler will always just be the last of the `i` variables.  The reason is that your `for` loop gets to the end before the asynchronous method gets handled.  As I understand it ES6 with `let` would fix this.

Comment: Doh, beginner's mistake! Thanks Forbes. I'm not into `let` yet, so have fixed it with a trad' closure.

Comment: yep, that works.  Personally I prefer "self calling" functions (see my answer), but either solution is equally valid.