# Loading large number of entries in an array causes web page to freeze

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asynchronous, freeze

I have a web page that loads large amount of entries through a promise call in AngularJS. The promise is resolved to an array that contains at least **4,000** entries (JSON object). When the data comes in from remote service, the web page `freezes` for 5 - 10 seconds, and a window always pops up asking if I want to stop the busy script. The code below is what I am currently doing:

```
promiseObj.then(function(data) {

//use async to handle each entry in data
async.each(data, function(entry) {

                    //handle entry here... omitted

                    //push in the processed entry
                    $scope.allSegs.push(entry);

                }, function(err) {
                    console.log("error in retrieving all data asynchronously: ", err);
                }); //async

});
```

To make the web page appear to be more responsive, I am thinking about splitting the large array (`data` as indicated in the above code) into multiple smaller arrays first, then use the '`async.each`' to handle each smaller array sequentially. or is it better to use an interval timer to handle this? I

Comment: why you don;t think about server side paging, obviously use would not view 4000 records at time..

Comment: i have no control over the server side, sorry

Comment: How about some client side paging? Render a limited portion of the data you've retrieved?

Comment: you mean AJAX paging? only load the data for the current page view? well that might be possible.

Comment: can you provide an example for the interceptor you suggested on $http request?

Comment: will this post help you as a guidance?

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497063/loading-large-datasets-with-angularjs

Comment: Yeah Nomesh's suggestion looks good, I was working on a spinoff of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kpxbrts0/) to see if it would work for you. Looks like it would.

Comment: Is the issue just loading the data or are you rendering it with an ng-repeat as well?

Comment: I use ng-repeat as well.

Comment: @Chris, thanks so much for your code on jsFiddle.

Comment: Have you looked at using virtual scrolling? It would remove the rendering limitation and watch count issue. One example of an implementation can be found here: https://github.com/EnzeyNet/VirtualScroll

Comment: thanks, it's first time I hear about virtual scrolling. I am reading it now, interesting!

Comment: Are you trying to show all 4000 entries in the view?

Comment: @Jagadish: Yes I need to show all entries on the page and use the datatables plugin from jquery to display the paginated entries.

Comment: @TonyGW: When you are displaying data in table, I would suggest you to use Angular components rather than jQuery components. You can use ng-table which provides lot of features required for a grid. I am not sure how you are binding 4000 entries to your jQuery table components to provide you solution. But when working on AngularJs application it is suggest that you can have atmost 2000 binding in a view. If there are more than 2000 binding then the application becomes slow.

Answer (score 0):

4000 is not so large number of items. The key factor is to not overload the $digest lifecycle of angular. In order to do this you can do some edit, for example:

1. why loop with `async.each` if you can simply assign `data` variable you already have to `$scope.allSegs` ?
2. how many attributes does `data` array have? Are all they essential in that place of code? Can you split data objects in smaller ones and load them separately in different times?
3. As suggested from several users above, pagination would be a useful solution